# nginx add header to specific URL on Zend Framework

Tags: json, zend-framework, cross-domain

I have a zend 1.x application and would like to add a header to a specific JSON request [not to all JSON requests]. For example anything that is requesting **/data.json** should have the **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** set.

I tried this config but it is not working [I tried to add generic headers and it is working so it seems that all the required modules are installed]. How would be possible to add the header just to the /data.json request ?

```
location /data.json  {
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
    add_header Cache-Control "public";
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;               
}   

# this part actually serves the zend files
## Parse all .php file in the directory       
location ~ .(php|phtml)$ {      
    fastcgi_pass   generic-fpm;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

So far I am adding the header directive in the php script that is generating the JSON response:

```
<?php     
   header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
?>
```

Comment: location ~ ^/data.json {
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
    add_header Cache-Control "public";
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;  
}

Answer (score 1):

You did forget the ~ in your expression!

```
location ~ ^/data.json { 
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
    add_header Cache-Control "public";
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}
```

Comment: thx for the tip, actually I missed the = sign [exact matched] the  ~ is used for regex matching. However still not working 100% as it seems that after the try_files condition the added headers are just going lost.

Comment: I'm sorry that I couldn't help. In my applications I always use a plugin (PHP code) to add custom headers, as some resources might use other headers, or even another client role might get different headers! So, your header() method would work.